# Python Calculate Rank in Field Esri

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, cursor

Does anyone know how to calculate the "rank" of a field but within 1-100?
For example i have a field called "ValSumBasin" with all these values. I am wanting to rank these values from 1-100.

I can rank it from 1-3084 but am wanting 1-100.
This is what I have so far:

```py
import arcpy

from itertools import count, groupby

fc = "my shapefile"
sort_fields = ["ValSumBasin"]
rank_field = "Rank"
sql_orderby = "ORDER BY {}".format(", ".join(sort_fields))
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,
                           sort_fields + [rank_field],
                           sql_clause=(None, sql_orderby)) as cur:
    cntr = count(1)
    for key, group in groupby(cur, lambda x: x[:-1]):
        dense_rank = next(cntr)
        for row in group:
            cur.updateRow(row[:-1] + [dense_rank])

del cur
```

Comment: Add a sample or screenshot of the attribute table

Comment: Try rank // 308 +1

Comment: Hey everytime I try add pic it doesn't let me submit.

Comment: Hey felixip where exactly do I put rank // 308 + 1? I'm beginner python